# Align symbols in plist

Tags: emacs, indentation

How can I align symbols in a plist? Take the following examples of default `'emacs-lisp-mode` indentation

```
'(:a 1
     :b 2
     :c 3)

(defhydra h (:color amaranth
                    :pre some-pre
                    :post some-post)
  nil)
```

How can I achieve the following indentation?

```
(defhydra h (:color amaranth
             :pre some-pre
             :post some-post)
  nil)
```

On a side note, is there a similar function for lisp like `c-show-syntactic-information` which is incredibly useful for this type of thing. I can't find anything with `apropos`.

Comment: One question per question, please.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10230/how-to-indent-keywords-aligned/10233#10233

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want Emacs to indent `defhydra` the same way it indents the Common
Lisp `defun`, so you put

```
(autoload 'common-lisp-indent-function "cl-indent" "Common Lisp indent.")
(custom-set-variables
 '(lisp-indent-function 'common-lisp-indent-function))
(put 'defhydra 'common-lisp-indent-function 'defun)
```

into your `.emacs` and edit your hydra files in `lisp-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous answer, `common-lisp-indent-function` will indent plists as desired. However, I didn't want to globally change the indent-function, so this is just a wrapper to indent a region with `common-lisp-indent-function` and toggle it on/off with prefix.

```
(defun my-cl-indent (&optional start end switch)
  "Indent region with `common-lisp-indent-function'. With prefix
toggle buffer-local value to be `common-lisp-indent-function'."
  (interactive "r\nP")
  (when switch
    (setq-local lisp-indent-function
                (if (eq lisp-indent-function 'lisp-indent-function)
                    'common-lisp-indent-function
                  'lisp-indent-function)))
  (let ((lisp-indent-function 'common-lisp-indent-function))
    (put 'cl-flet 'common-lisp-indent-function
         (get 'flet 'common-lisp-indent-function))
    (indent-region start end)))
```